# C#: WPF datagrid and xml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, validation, datagrid

How can I read a xml file using a class and populate it on a datagrid? The datagrid should have validation capabilities?

Xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Data>
 <Book>
 <Author>John Doe</Author>
 <Title>Straight Track Demo</Title>
 <Version>1</Version>  
 </Book>
</Data>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  There are numerous DataGrid and Linq2Xml examples out there.  Have you even attempted this yet?

Comment: I've seen a few examples but is getting stumped by doing it from the class instead of xaml.

Comment: I suppose that was a leading question; I was trying to get you to tell us what you have already tried so that we can show you why it isn't working.  Easier to learn that way.

Comment: I read it using xdocument.load, xdocument.descendants and this.datagrid1.itemssource from MainWindow.xaml.cs and I did the validation using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975.aspx. I've also used datagridtemplate column, datatemplate and textbox to fill the grid. I just wonder how I could read the xml file using a class and do validation and populating all from code-behind. For example, a class that reads any xml file, and a way to display the file on the datagrid

Comment: @user641631 - Please edit your original question and add the code sample there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can load up a DataGrid with XML (there are others as well):

1. Using an [XmlDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx)
2. Reading the XML in from the code-behind

Here's a very crude sample that uses both methods.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyDataGrid"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MyDataGrid" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>

        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="BookData" 
            Source="C:\Somewhere\Books.xml" XPath="Data"/>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Book]}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" 
            Name="dataGrid1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Author" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Author].Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Title" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Title].Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Version" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Version].Value}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>


        <DataGrid 
            DataContext="{StaticResource BookData}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Book}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" 
            Name="dataGrid2" Margin="0,25,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Author" 
                    Binding="{Binding XPath=Author}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Title" 
                    Binding="{Binding XPath=Title}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Version" 
                    Binding="{Binding XPath=Version}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyDataGrid.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyDataGrid : Window
    {
        public MyDataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var xml = XDocument.Load( "c:\\Somewhere\\Books.xml" ).Root;
            dataGrid1.DataContext = xml;
        }

    }
}
```

### For Reference

Finally, here are a couple of articles:

1. [Binding.XPath Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx)
2. [Customize Data Display with Data Binding and WPF > Using XML Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx#id0190068)
3. [A DataGrid sample using XML data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/11/25/a-datagrid-sample-using-xml-data.aspx)