# autogenerate column datagrid xml

Tags: xml, wpf, datagrid

How to get this XML style into an autogenerated column datagrid ? Can't seem to get it working... (I get column header with "Child" and "innertext" and ... very weard)

xml:

```
  <response>
    <sms>
      <recipient></recipient>
      <message></message>
      <status></status>
    </sms>
  </response>
```

xaml:

```
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="LogData" XPath="/response/sms">

        </XmlDataProvider>

        ...

       <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource LogData}}" DataContext="  {StaticResource LogData}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
        ...
```

Comment: Does answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238534/c-wpf-datagrid-and-xml-file) help?

Comment: I think that better way is create columns manually/

Comment: No because I have multipl different xml files that needs to be in that datagrid. But the xml files does not all have the same element under the "sms" element...so therefor I need to use autogenerate

Answer (score 0):

XML is specifically not supported for autogenerate

[DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns Propert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)

> DataGrid cannot auto-generate columns when the source is XML data.

Comment: Damn, how to solve my problem then ? Multiple xml files with different elementsnames, into 1 datagrid (sepperatly I mean)