# Loading XML Data into a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, dataset

In my WPF app the following should be possible:

reading in XML Data and presenting them in the User Interface.

To this end I defined a dataGrid in the MainPage.xaml file:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"/>
```

In the code-behind-file I created a method to fill this datagrid with data from an xml-file:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(path/to/xml-file.xml);

dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.?????
```

As you can see from the code, I do not know what to do after  "dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet."

Under the following link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/load-an-xml-file-into-a-wpf-datagrid/

it is claimed that the following would suffice:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

However, this throws an exception:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException:'Table 0 cannot be found'.

My question is therefore, what to put there instead.

Comment: better use XMLDataProvider instead of dataset, msdn [How to: Bind to XML Data Using an XMLDataProvider and XPath Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You might look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238534/c-wpf-datagrid-and-xml-file. this will solve your problem.

Comment: `it doesn't work` - it does not compile, or it throws exception? or the data is not correct? or the layout of the datagrid is not what you expect?

Comment: This will work `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;` provided `DataGrid's` `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to `True`.

Comment: @Nikhil: I had tried it with the AutoGenerateColumns property set to true but it didn't work either.

Comment: @keeyzx: it throws an exception when running the program:
"System.IndexOutOfRangeException:'Table 0 cannot be found'.

Comment: @user2932395: Thank you for the link.

Comment: Can you post the content of the XML file? Is it an empty XML?