# no data, no exception when loading XML Data into WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid

In my WPF app the following should be possible:

reading in XML Data and presenting them in the User Interface.

To this end I defined a dataGrid in the MainPage.xaml file:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

In the code-behind-file I created a method to fill this datagrid with data from an xml-file:

```
private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
     {
         string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dlg.FileName);
         var xml = XDocument.Load(path).Root;
         dataGrid.DataContext = xml;
     }
}
```

This compiles fine and also runs fine (whithout throwing an exception) - however, the xml-data is not displayed in the UI.

When using the debugger, there are several strange things:

> 1. the variable "path" in the watch window looks as follows the whole time:path    error CS0103: The name 'path' does not exist in the current context
> 2. for some reason, the line

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(path).Root;
```

seems to be "jumped over". That is, the debugger goes directly from

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dlg.FileName);
```

to

```
dataGrid.DataContext = xml;
```

I don't really understand what's going on here.

Comment: "Jumped over" doesn't make sense. What was the decision process that led to trying to populate a DataGrid by setting `DataContext`?

Comment: I used what was proposed under the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238534/c-wpf-datagrid-and-xml-file
 ... see the section on "Code Behind" in the approved answer

Comment: Can you identify the instance of `XmlDataProvider` in your code?

Comment: I thought you use either XmlDataProvider or a "Code Behind" approach ... I don't have an instance of XMLDataProvider

Comment: You used a code-behind approach, so fortunately you're spared the horrors of trying to make `XmlDataProvider` work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using an `XmlDataProvider`, there's not a lot to be gained by using one or two fragments of that approach to the problem and leaving out the rest. `XmlDataProvider` is weird and anything involving it is going to be a workaround.

In WPF, you populate a `DataGrid`, or any "collection control" (`ListBox`, `ComboBox`, etc.) by setting or binding `ItemsSource`. That's the property that populates these things with a collection. The answer you looked at is just an ugly workaround to enable `ItemsSource` to be bound when `XmlDataProvider` is being used. `DataContext` is a much more general property that any WPF control has. It's the *source* that bindings use to find the properties you bind to. You're not binding anything, so worry about that later.

Since you're doing this in codebehind, this is quick and it works with the sample XML I've included at the bottom of this answer:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dlg.FileName);

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(path);
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataView;
    }
}
```

I'd probably either create POCO objects from the XML and expose those in a collection on a viewmodel, or if I were in a great hurry I might have the viewmodel expose a `DataView` as above. But if you haven't already gone MVVM with this project, you may as well leave that for the next one.

XML:

```
<Items>
  <Item Foo="0" Bar="A" />
  <Item Foo="1" Bar="B" />
  <Item Foo="2" Bar="C" />
  <Item Foo="3" Bar="D" />
</Items>
```

This works too:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Foo>0</Foo>
    <Bar>A</Bar>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Foo>1</Foo>
    <Bar>B</Bar>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Comment: Now, using this code, I'm getting the following error message: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurred Message=Table 0 cannot be found."

Comment: @Tommy Can I see the exact code that's throwing that exception?

Comment: sure, I can send you the whole thing ... it's just about 100 lines of code in the MainPage.xaml.c file

Comment: No send, only post. I doubt that I need anything that doesn't touch the XML and/or the DataGrid. Questions aren't size limited, just stick four dashes in a row above the update and the markdown will create a horizontal bar.

Comment: You can forget about the first method (which is for text files and works fine) ... the method not working is: mnuOpen2_Click

Comment: @Tommy Is this a Release build? Does the code work at runtime and you're just having trouble in the debugger, or what? Can you show me the XML? Did you try it with my test XML?

Comment: I started it in Release mode, yes

Comment: The debugger isn't going to work well in Release mode. Start it in Debug mode and do a clean build.

Comment: I updated the post with info on what happens in debug mode

Comment: Looks like the XML can't be interpreted a table, at least not by the rules that `DataSet.ReadXml()` uses to do so. Let's see the XML.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>Test</text>

Comment: that's the xml ... in the file, the text tag is in the second row

Comment: @Tommy OK, that resolves that issue. There's no imaginable way for that to be interpreted as a sequence of rows in a table. I've shown you XML that can be so interpreted. Anything else?

Comment: I also tried it with your example ... and it didn't work

Comment: <Items>
  <Item Foo="0" Bar="A" />
  <Item Foo="1" Bar="B" />
  <Item Foo="2" Bar="C" />
  <Item Foo="3" Bar="D" />
</Items>

Comment: @Tommy If that is the entire content of the XML file, it should work.

Comment: @Tommy I just tested with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` header, works fine that way too.

Comment: @Tommy Are you confirming in the debugger that you opened the correct file?

Comment: So why doesn't it? ... Can I send you the whole project plus the two testfiles I used and you run it on your computer once?

Comment: "Are you confirming in the debugger that you opened the correct file?" No, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144395/discussion-between-ed-plunkett-and-tommy).